# Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, set

I am wanting to use a set in a Google Sheets Script. I use and add values to and have checked the size of the set to be correct. Yet, when I return the set with the hope of the values displaying in the column I call my function from nothing is displayed.

Are sets not able to be used in this way? Did I just make an error? Any help would be appreciated!

```
function duplicateRemover(values) { // needs to removed duplicates
  var set = new Set();
  if(undefined !== values){
    values = values.sort();
    values = values.reverse();
    var x = 0;
    var setSize = 0;
    while(x < values.length){
      set.add(values[x]);
      x++;
    }

  }
  return set;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your issue. In order to correctly understand about your issue, can you provide the sample values of both `values` and `set` you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: what is the usage of this function? Are you trying to display the set directly in the sheet?

Comment: What are your ```values``` parameter? Cell values?